# Hide the part of site address in toolbar browser in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, toolbar

I want to hide part of the address in the browser toolbar in asp.net.

For example, if it's `http://mysite.com/News/Shownews.aspx?ID=-1&Num=20`, it should change to `http://mysite.com/` on every page.

I visit some websites that do exactly like this. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you add some links to the sites that you do this, to understand the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: You can't directly control what's in the browser toolbar.  You could, I suppose, come up with a redirect that would take the URL given, put the data into session, and redirect to the home page, which would render based on what's in session.  That would be a bad idea.  Alternately (and this is probably what you've seen on other sites), you could put your whole application inside a frame or iframe.

Comment: Can I ask why? I personally hate it when there's non-useful URLs - you can't bookmark or copy links to things.

Comment: Can you show us websites that do the same?

Comment: @CorrugatedAir: Because i think it is a hack hole. You sometimes can hack these website easly!

Comment: @SaeedTalaee there is no way hiding get and post parameters from user, this is a silly way to make your app secure

Comment: I want to hide the id. and show some thing else instead od it.like this:
blogfa.com

Comment: @SaeedTalaee as i said, you can't hide it from anyone who is able to use it as a tool to hack into your website.

Comment: @SaeedTalaee Won't the ID be submitted with the form/link anyway (otherwise how would you know what you're going to end up showing)? That's really easy to see/spoof if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, URL rewriting is what you're looking for most likely: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx is a broad overview of the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [UrlRewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).
Or, you can use asp.net mvc, it has routing feature.

Comment: But rewriting URLs or using routing still implies that different pages have different URLs -- they're just cleaner URLs.  The OP wants every page to have the same URL.

Comment: @JacobM true, but this is as close (while staying sane) as possible to what he wants. I think he is not 100% sure what he wants and if he has seen some websites doing it, it's most likely url rewrite.

Comment: I want url rewriting toolbar.

Comment: @SaeedTalaee plz show us more examples and explanations that make sense to get real help

Comment: To start, that's a horrible practice, and users can't directly access specific areas of the site as a result.  Two ways come to mind besides URL rewriting... MVC routing & partial views of a single .aspx page.

Comment: I want to hide the id. and show some thing else instead od it.like this: blogfa.com

Comment: @JacobM look, he does want url rewrite after all :)

Answer (score 1):

No idea why you would do such a thing, but some hacky solution comes to mind:

- `http://mysite.com/News/Shownews.aspx?ID=-1&Num=20` will respond with a redirect to `http://mysite.com/` and stashes whatever information is necessary in cookie/session state/... (like ie. the complete original request URL)
- The controller handling `http://mysite.com/` grabs the state and renders the appropriate output

Of course this might introduce some race conditions dependent on the exact method used to store the relevant state.

All in all that whole undertaking is a pretty bad idea thinking of principles like REST...but since you asked for it...